# Converting DOM pixel coordinates to latlng coordinates

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to get the latlng coordinates of the bottom left and top right corners of an svg element (orange box in the picture) I overlayed on top of the map. However, the latlng coordinates I am getting from transforming the pixel coordinates is off by a wide margin.

Coordinates I should be getting from this view:

BL: [-18.9, -39.1],
TR: [48.8, 39.3]

Coordinates I am actually getting:

BL: [-30.3, 127.0],
TR: [40.9, 205.9]

[image: The orange box is the overlayed svg element]

This is the code I am using to determine the pixel position:

```
this.navigation.on('moveend zoomend', () => {
  const bounds = L.DomUtil.get("compBorder")!.getBoundingClientRect();

  const bl1 = L.point(bounds.left, bounds.bottom)
  const tr1 = L.point(bounds.right, bounds.top)

  const bl = this.navigation.layerPointToLatLng(bl1);
  const tr = this.navigation.layerPointToLatLng(tr1);

  this.cs.setBlTr([bl.lat, bl.lng], [tr.lat, tr.lng]);
  this.cs.setCenter(this.navigation.getCenter());
  this.cs.setZoom(this.navigation.getZoom());
});
```

From what I am seeing it doesn't seem to make a difference whether I use the layerPointToLatlng() or the containerPointToLatlng() function.

Comment: The values returned from `getBoundingClientRect()` are relative to the whole page, no to the map container. What is the position of the map relative to the page?

Comment: You can see its position [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y638r.jpg).

In terms of html, it's positioned to be within the map div:
`<div id="navigation"><svg id="compBorder" ></svg> </div>`

Comment: That was more of a rethorical question to make you think. If the map is not at the [0,0] top-left corner of the page, you must account for that. I'm also suspecting this is a kind of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that should be fixed better by knowing how that SVG rectangle gets created in the first place.

Comment: I found a fix by just grabbing the position of the parent. Thanks for the reply!
[fix](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/javascript+get+element+position+relative+to+parent)